# Binding Between elements inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding

How can I make binding between properties of two elements inside dataTemplate ?

example :
// Bind Text property to Content property

```
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
  <Label Content="{Binding}" />
</Datatemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood.

```
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox x:Name="p_text" Text="{Binding login}"/>
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=p_text, Path Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```